# Convert Row Column Data To Row By SQL Statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I current using oracle 11g here is problem that i face. I have a SQL statement show as below:

```
 SELECT A.LM_PERSON_ID
 ,A.LM_GRADE
 ,C.COURSE_STR
 ,Decode (A.LM_GRADE,'001','1','002','2','003','3') AS JOB_GRADE


 FROM PS_LM_PERSON_JOB A
,PS_LM_LPLN_LRN B 
,PS_LM_LPLN_DTL C 
,PS_LM_ENRLMT D
,PS_LM_CI_TBL E 


WHERE A.LM_EMPL_RCD='0'
AND A.LM_EFFSEQ=(SELECT Max(A1.LM_EFFSEQ) FROM PS_LM_PERSON_JOB A1 
WHERE A.LM_PERSON_ID=A1.LM_PERSON_ID AND A.EFFDT=A1.EFFDT 
AND A.LM_EMPL_RCD=A1.LM_EMPL_RCD)
AND A.LM_ACTIVE='Y'
AND A.EFFDT=(SELECT Max(A2.EFFDT) FROM PS_LM_PERSON_JOB A2 
WHERE A.LM_PERSON_ID=A2.LM_PERSON_ID AND A.LM_EMPL_RCD=A2.LM_EMPL_RCD 
AND A.LM_EFFSEQ=A2.LM_EFFSEQ) 
AND A.LM_PERSON_ID=B.LM_PERSON_ID (+)  
AND B.LM_LPLN_ID=C.LM_LPLN_ID (+) 
AND B.LM_PERSON_ID=C.LM_PERSON_ID (+)
AND C.LM_ENRLMT_ID=D.LM_ENRLMT_ID (+)  
AND D.LM_CI_ID=E.LM_CI_ID (+)
AND E.EFFDT=(SELECT Max(E1.EFFDT) FROM PS_LM_CI_TBL E1 WHERE E.LM_CI_ID=E1.LM_CI_ID)


ORDER BY A.LM_PERSON_ID
```

The output i would like to have was:

```
  JOB GRADE   COURSE_STR.A    COURSE_STR.B    COURSE_STR.C 
    1              5               3               1
    2              4               2               2
    3              1               1               1
```

Can someone mind to share how you able to do it? Thank you very much.

Comment: :hey dude can you give the all table description!

Comment: Sure~
PS_LM_PERSON_JOB A= All Person details such as age, nationality will be in this table. 
PS_LM_LPLN_LRN B = Specific course ID
PS_LM_LPLN_DTL C = Table to store course details such as cost, training hours and so on. And course name in the COURSE_STR field in this table. 
PS_LM_ENRLMT D = Person who entitle with the selected course.
PS_LM_CI_TBL E = Check person who entitle with the course have been completed or not.

Comment: no man column names!table structures yar

Comment: Very sorry to said i only can provide you the field name. What else information you wish to know?

Comment: dude..i feel your table and column names are not straight forward so i want to know which table has wish column and it's name yar!!

Comment: For the PS_LM_PERSON_JOB table consist of job_grade such as '1','2' &'3'. And the PS_LM_LPLN_DTL consist of course_details. While LM_LPLN_LRN B ,PS_LM_ENRLMT D AND ,PS_LM_CI_TBL E consist of some private data that i didn't show at there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [PIVOT](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) operator and see if it solves your problem.

If you had provided more information I could attempt at writing your query.
Perhaps a simple example of the query result without transformation would be enough.

**EDIT :**

let's imagine the test table:

```
CREATE TABLE pivot_test (
  job_grade            NUMBER,
  course_str    VARCHAR2(1)
);

INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1, 'B');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1, 'C');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1, 'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (1, 'C');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (2, 'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (2, 'B');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (2, 'C');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (2, 'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (3, 'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (3, 'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (3, 'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (3, 'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (3, 'A');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (3, 'B');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (3, 'B');
INSERT INTO pivot_test VALUES (3, 'A');
COMMIT;
```

Our test data looks like:

```
select * from pivot_test;

 JOB_GRADE COURSE_STR
---------- ----------
         1 A
         1 B
         1 C
         1 A
         1 C
         2 A
         2 B
         2 C
         2 A
         3 A
         3 A
         3 A
         3 A
         3 A
         3 B
         3 B
         3 A

17 rows selected
```

Now we apply the PIVOT operation, and obtain the result:

```
SQL> SELECT *
  2        FROM pivot_test
  3        PIVOT(COUNT(course_str) FOR course_str IN('A' AS "COURSE_STR.A",
  4                                                  'B' AS "COURSE_STR.B",
  5                                                  'C' AS "COURSE_STR.C"));

 JOB_GRADE COURSE_STR.A COURSE_STR.B COURSE_STR.C
---------- ------------ ------------ ------------
         1            2            1            2
         2            2            1            1
         3            6            2            0

SQL>
```

I used COUNT() as an aggregation function but it could be SUM(), MAX(), etc.

Hope this helps

Comment: This is the example of pivot that i try to create. Unfortunately, it give me error message. You may have a look.

Comment: SELECT * FROM (
SELECT A.LM_GRADE FROM PS_LM_PERSON_JOB A
WHERE A.LM_EMPL_RCD='0'
AND A.LM_EFFSEQ=(SELECT Max(A1.LM_EFFSEQ) FROM PS_LM_PERSON_JOB A1 WHERE A.LM_PERSON_ID=A1.LM_PERSON_ID AND A.EFFDT=A1.EFFDT AND A.LM_EMPL_RCD=A1.LM_EMPL_RCD)
AND A.LM_ACTIVE='Y'
AND A.EFFDT=(SELECT Max(A2.EFFDT) FROM PS_LM_PERSON_JOB A2 WHERE A.LM_PERSON_ID=A2.LM_PERSON_ID AND A.LM_EMPL_RCD=A2.LM_EMPL_RCD AND A.LM_EFFSEQ=A2.LM_EFFSEQ) 

)SRC
PIVOT
(Decode (LM_GRADE,'001','1','002','2','003','3') AS JOB_GRADE

) PIV

Comment: I think you are not applying the PIVOT syntax correctly. You have to use an aggregation function like SUM() our COUNT(). Please check my edited answer for an example similar to what you want (I think).

Comment: hi dude, i will test ur method on next week. because now i am on vacation~ (^^). Cheer up.

Comment: Neves, you provide a very good solution for me. Because my mistake was i try pivot all after link all table together instead of create a new table.

Comment: Glad I could help! But you don't need to create a new table to apply the PIVOT operator, you can use it directly in any query. Also, if I solved your problem please accept the solution :) Cheers

Comment: would you mind to explain in details how to muse it without create a new table? Because i link quite a few table together.(^^)

Comment: The easiest way is to wrap your query and use the PIVOT operator in the end. Alternatively, you can use it directly in the query but sometimes it makes it harder to read afterwards. Using the "wrap" method, imagine the last query I gave above. Now you could simply replace the `SELECT * FROM pivot_test PIVOT ...` by `SELECT * FROM (your query) PIVOT ...`

Comment: So that mean i need to create a view as well in order to wrap it?

Comment: No, you can do it without creating any extra object. But if it's easier for you to create an additional object (table/view), then go for it. I am just telling you the most efficient way to do it ;). Don't you know how to use subqueries? You just have to make you query a subquery of the PIVOT query.

Comment: O ic ic~yup i knew how to use sub-query. Anyway thank you very much for your help. (^^)